# List comprehension with dynamic value changing

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, generator

I have 2 variables. They stay in a reverse connection and form a list with 2 values which sum equals to 1. The example is shown below:

```
[0.1, 0.9], [0.2, 0.8], ..., [0.9, 0.1]
```

Is it possible to create a list generator that is able to do this?

So I want the following list of lists as a result:

```
[[0.1, 0.9], [0.2, 0.8], ..., [0.9, 0.1]]
```

I know, I can use a `for` loop for it, however, I'd like to know about this opportunity.

Comment: Just a tip for you, the "2 values which sum equals to 1" are called complementary numbers where they complement into 1. Complement basically means that whatever the first number is missing, the second will have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like

```
[[z / 10, (10 - z) / 10] for z in range(1, 10)]
```

This formulation attempts to reduce rounding error as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can zip the lists:

```
z=[[j/10,i/10] for i,j in zip([x for x in range(10)],[y for y in range(10,-1,-1)])]
```